# Using gdal to convert SInt16 DEM to UInt16 DEM, while setting nodata value to 0xFFFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, nodata

Can this be done on the command line?

I'm working with the Mars MOLA DEM GeoTIFF. Unfortunately, my framework can't deal with signed values, so it gets really confused when it looks at the data. I want to translate it to unsigned, and I want to adjust all the nodata values to 0xFFFFU.

The data set has values ranging from -8,500 to 21,226, and the nodata value is -32,768 (0x8000). I'd like to add 8500 to all the pixel values, change any nodata(0x8000) pixels to the new nodata value of (0xFFFF), and set the nodata value tag to 0xFFFF (65535).

I can't figure out how to get gdal to change any nodata values in the input dataset.

Comment: Set the nodata value in the band of the output dataset to 65535 after writing the array to the band. Flush the cache. Always flush the cache.

Comment: Sorry, I just clarified the question: I want to do this on the command line, if possible.

Comment: gdal_edit.py can change nodata. gdal_calc.py to do the arithmetic. -ot to change the type. I haven't tried it yet :-]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, just using gdal_calc.py:

```
gdal_calc.py  -A a1.tif  --outfile=a3.tif  --calc="(A<-9000)*65535 + (A>0)*A+8500" --NoDataValue=65535 --type=Int32 --overwrite
```

- converts to Int32
- shifts the valid data up by 8500
- shifts and sets the nodata value to 0xFFFF

You might need to change the nodata test as my nodata value was -9999 but I think it will work as-is.

Comment: That's helpful, seeing how calc works. But can the final file be UInt16?

Comment: Yes. I was experimenting...